# Set Authentication Cookie via ASP.Net Page Method. Possible?

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

I have an ASP.Net page with a page method which accepts the username and password and validates the user. Since its a page method the username and password is sent to the server with the use of JavaScript in the usual way page methods are called.

Is it possible to set an authentication cookie in some way so that all subsequent page requests identify themselves as the logged in user? or isn't page methods the way to go when authenticating users?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set an authentication cookie in some way so that all subsequent page requests identify themselves as the logged in user?

Yes, you could use the [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) method if you are using [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). This will emit an authentication cookie into the Response so that all subsequent requests send this cookie allowing you to track the user.

Comment: can u please give me a small code of page method where Authentication cookie will be set via page method and send the success message to client which will be capture by jquery and display before user. thanks